# Left Join ou Not Exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, query

Precisei resgatar informações que constavam em uma determinada tabela, mas não estavam em outra. 
Pesquisando encontrei que o NOT EXISTS serviria para esse caso, porém vi que o Left Join traz o mesmo resultado:

**NOT EXISTS**

```
select pedido from logintegracao as A
where not exists (select * from pagamento as B where B.idPedido = A.Pedido)
```

Plano de Execução:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**LEFT JOIN**

```
select * from logintegracao as A
left join pagamento as B on A.Pedido = B.idpedido
where B.idpedido is null
```

Plano de Execução

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Qual Query teria a melhor performance? 
As duas maneiras estão corretas?

Comment: As duas madeiras estão corretas.

Comment: As duas são corretas e a performance é a mesma também, se mudar mudaria bem pouco.

Comment: Segundo este artigo: [Should I use NOT IN, OUTER APPLY, LEFT OUTER JOIN, EXCEPT, or NOT EXISTS?](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join), na presença de um indice o `NOT EXISTS` apresenta um melhor desempenho... apenas preste atenção para não fazer um `not exists (select * ...)`, até pq você só precisa de uma coluna.

Comment: Você pode executar ambas as queries mandando mostrar o "execution plan" e postar aqui os planos de execução gerados? É isso que vai dizer o que terá melhor performance, assim como a estrutura do seu banco e índices.

Comment: Boa ideia bfavaretto, adicionei o Plano de Execução das duas Queries

Comment: Não existe uma regra de bolo para esses casos de sempre utilizar um ou outro. O ideal é rodar o explain da query e analisar o que pode melhorar pelo execution plan.

Comment: Qual chave da tabela PAGAMENTO ?

Answer (score 1):

As duas maneiras estão corretas, mais acredito que o LEFT JOIN seja melhor pelo fato de não utilizar **subselect**.