# Mysql problema com query com coluna vazia

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma ***Query*** onde dou um select com ***INNER JOIN*** entre duas tabelas (contatos e empresa), eu tenho um campo denominado id_empresa onde faço a busca na tabela empresas para buscar o nome da empresa, porém o campo id_empresa não é obrigatório, portanto tem alguns contatos com o campo id_empresa = 0, poderia solucionar isso com dois ***SELECT***, porém não acho ser a melhor forma. 
Vi em alguns casos a utilização de IF e ELSE na query, porém não tenho dominio dessa utilização. 
a query até agora que estou usando com erro, poís exibe apenas as empresas que tem o campo id_empresa diferente de 0 (vazio):

```
SELECT c.nome,c.telefone1,c.email,e.nome AS empresa
FROM contatos AS c JOIN empresas AS e WHERE  c.id_empresa = e.id
```

penso em uma solução de uma query única, onde quando a id_empresa for 0, retornar o nome da empresa vazio ou nulo.

Comment: ele não tem empresa. no formulário não é obrigatório inserir uma empresa.

Comment: Veja se minha resposta te atende, fiz um exemplo online também para facilitar.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Left Join ou Not Exists](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/102925/left-join-ou-not-exists)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode retornar todos os contatos independente da existência de uma empresa utilizando `LEFT JOIN`:

**LEFT JOIN:**

Retorna todos os registros da tabela esquerda (tabela A) e as correspondências que existirem com a tabela direita (tabela B).

```
SELECT contatos.nome
   , contatos.telefone1
   , contatos.email
   , empresas.nome AS empresa 
FROM contatos 
LEFT JOIN empresas 
   ON contatos.id_empresa = empresas.id;
```

[SQLFiddle - Veja funcionando online](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2ea5d/1)